# How to auto-populate User.Identity.Name into MVC 4 intranet form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4.1

I am building my first MVC site using MVC 4 in C# and Entity Framework 4.1. I have a model that displays a list of items with standard "add", "edit", "details", and "delete" options.

The database that's linked to the model has a column for "Username" and my application currently displays a text box for the user to enter their username via the following code from the Create.cshtml file.

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>
```

I'm trying to alter this so that their User.Identity.Name (e.g. DOMAIN\user) value will either auto-populate in the text box, or even better, just be stored without showing the user that it's happening.

Is there a relatively painless way to accomplish this?

EDIT: My Controller code for the "create" section currently looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult Create(Occurrence occurrence)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Occurrences.Add(occurrence);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeID", "EmployeeName", occurrence.EmployeeID);
        return View(occurrence);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the username in the controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    string username = Environment.UserName // or however you get it
    User user = new User{UserName = username};
    return View(user);
}
```

another option is to handle it in the view

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, new{@Value = Environment.UserName})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure I understand. How will adding this to the Index section reflect a change on the Create section?

Comment: that was a mistype, it should have been create. I changed that. Your current create ActionResult is probably passing an empty model, so the value showing up is empty. Now that you have a value there it should appear by default.